# R : How to join several lists of a single element into a single list of an element

Tags: r, list

I need to join several elements of a list (each of the elements is a long character), in a single list also of a character.

```
mylist <- list("values 10 15 25 30 35 36 36", "values 10 17 75 35 45 36 76")

mylist

[[1]]
[1] "values 10 15 25 30 35 36 36"

[[2]]
[1] "values 10 17 75 35 45 36 76"
```

The result I hope to get is:

```
mylist2 <- list("values 10 15 25 30 35 36 36 10 17 75 35 45 36 76")

mylist2

[[1]]
[1] "values 10 15 25 30 35 36 36 10 17 75 35 45 36 76"
```

I need it to work for lists with more than 2 items.

Comment: All element of the list are starting by `values` ?

Answer (score 2):

Paste the components together giving a plain string, remove space followed by the word `values` and then turn that into a one component list:

```
list(gsub(" values", "", do.call("paste", mylist)))
```

If `values` could be any purely alphabetic single word then replace `" values"` with `" [[:alpha:]]+"` in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

`paste0("values ",gsub(".*?(\\d+.*)","\\1",mylist), collapse = " ")` can give what you want

```
> paste0("values ",gsub(".*?(\\d+.*)","\\1",mylist), collapse = " ")
[1] "values 10 15 25 30 35 36 36 values 10 17 75 35 45 36 76"
```